# Git and Apache sharing permissions on the webroot

Tags: linux, git

I have a bare git repo on my server in `/home/git/repos/myproject.git`. I can push code from my machine to this bare repository, which calls a `post-update` hook to push code to the webroot.

This only works if the git user owns the web files, but the server only works if the apache user owns the files.

I've created a new group `gitapache` and added both users to it. Then chowning the group ownership to this group, but it does not work.

The permissions are currently at 664 for all files and directories.

Is there a way of making this work?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to solve this is on my webserver is making a symbolic link from my webroot to my git repository. So no need to copy or hook or push anything, just update the files in my repository, and they're live.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't work as the repository is bare so doesn't store any code. I'll keep it in mind though.